# Here are two fractions, $\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{7}{8}$, which of these fractions are closer to $\frac{3}{4}$?

Tags: fractions

I've been throwing this question around my family. No one has a clue, therefore can someone help?

I'm pretty sure this will be easy to do

Comment: I think you're going to find that when you ask people for help, telling them what they "must" do is unlikely to make them feel like helping you.   This is a lesson that goes beyond math.stackexchange.

Comment: Really sorry, is is my first time using this site

Comment: I copied the question from my paper exactly, that's why

Comment: **Hint:** Convert the fractions to a common denominator.

Comment: Start with this:  Here are two numbers:  5 and 9.  Which is closer to 8?  Now think about exactly how you figured that out, and apply the same method to your problem with the fractions.

Comment: In this situation I filled in the missing numbers , that is 5,6,7,8,9 . Here I can see clearly that 8 is closer to 9. I suppose You mean I should do the same with fractions but am going blank when it comes to doing the same with fractions.

Comment: @JoshuaMbewe Did you read my comment ?

Answer (score 3):

Calculus suggestion is straight on the money: write the three fractions involved in this problem with a common denominator, say $\;24\; $:

$$\begin{align}&\frac23=\frac{16}{24}\\{}\\
&\frac78=\frac{21}{24}\\{}\\
&\color{red}{\frac34=\frac{18}{24}}\end{align}$$

Well, so which fraction is the closest one to the red one **and why**? Complete the reasoning.

Comment: I see 24 is common to all the fractions. Therefore  21 is closer to the red.

Comment: Beg your pardon 16/24 is closer

Comment: @Laxcity Indeed so.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between real numbers $x$ and $y$ is $|x-y|$. So the distance from $\frac{2}{3}$ to $\frac{3}{4}$ is
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{2}{3}-\frac{3}{4}\Big|=\Big|\frac{8}{12}-\frac{9}{12}\Big|=\frac{1}{12}.
\end{align*}
And the distance from $\frac{7}{8}$ to $\frac{3}{4}$ is
\begin{align*}
\Big|\frac{7}{8}-\frac{3}{4}\Big|=\Big|\frac{7}{8}-\frac{6}{8}\Big|=\frac{1}{8}.
\end{align*}
Since $\frac{1}{12}<\frac{1}{8}$, then $\frac{2}{3}$ is closer to $\frac{3}{4}$ than $\frac{7}{8}$ is.